# Spree AJAX API call 404'ing due to wrong base URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

So I'm currently getting 404 errors from dynamic loading fields in Spree on Ruby on Rails.

I've checked my `rake routes` to ensure that the API route is present, it is.

However I have mounted the Spree engine under a different base URL in config/routes.rb

`mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/shop'`

So all in all, dynamic loading fields are querying the API with:
 `http://<site>/api/v1/states?country_id=232`
instead of `http://<site>/shop/api/v1/states?country_id=232`

Is there an extra route I need to add to my routes.rb file? Or something more sinister?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a cache issue.

Fixed by setting the spree engine mount point to the root path.

`mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/'`

Then flushing the spree cache via the admin panel.